# Sharepoint List Question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, custom-form, content-approval, approval-process

I have many people filling out list items over a few days and saving as they go.
Once they are finished there is a dropdown on the list that they set to "Complete"

1. Can I easily see what columns are not completed using a filter/view?
2. Can I somehow setup a weekly report to show me  how many items do not have their dropdown item set to complete?
3. Can I set the list up so that they cannot set the column to complete unless I or 3 other specific team members signoff on their specific list item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes - you should be able to check this if you already have the
   proper access.  You can start with a personal view if you don't want
   other to see it (or use a listview webpart on a page with a custom
   view if you want to control access that way).
2. You have a variety of options but they depend on the configuration
   of    the farm.

   Custom listview (targeted at items changed in last week)

   Excel Desktop Client

   Excel Services with list Data source

   PowerPivot

   Reporting Services

   Powerview

   The last 4 are more difficult to setup than a listview but offer more power.
3. Use custom approval workflow and you can "reset" that column if approvals are not recieved (or automatilcy set it if all approvals are).

EDIT:
I'm assuming you are using a default list form or an InfoPath form with promoted columns.  If you are using an InfoPath form without promoted columns, you need to promote them so they are accessible via the library/list or use some type of custom submit options to write out specific values to your list or another list.